# jQueryMobile - Scroll to a position onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, scroll

In jQueryMobile, on the page load, I would like to scroll to a given position. I know how to do it in classic jQuery, but in jQueryMobile there is an auto scroll top on the page load.

I tried to do :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.mobile.silentScroll(1000);
});
```

That doesn't work. My page stay blocked to the top of the page.

While if i click on a link with `onclick="$.mobile.silentScroll(1000);"` that works perfectly !

I just would like to scroll to a yPosition on the page load :) !

=======EDIT============

After suggestions of White Raven and Omar I've tried to do this :

```
    $( document ).delegate("#pagePkmn", "pageinit", function() {
        $.mobile.silentScroll(1000);
    });
```

OR this :

```
    $(document).one("pagecontainershow", function () {
        $.mobile.silentScroll(1000);
    });
```

But still no effect ...

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You could add a small delay to the scroll: setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(1000);}, 100); within the pagecontainershow: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/r9y7e9rw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $(document).ready() is a bad idea:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/faq/dom-ready-not-working.html

It is recommended to use **pageinit**

=== EDIT ===

You can always use the ghetto way:

```
setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(1000);}, 1000);  // scroll after 1 second
```

Comment: Ok thanks that works :) ! Could I set TimeOut to 1ms or 10ms ? To get the effect as instant ? What problem this way can occur ?

Comment: DOM will not finish loading if the value is too low. You can use a combination of onload and setTimeout like: `<body onload="scrollit()"></body>

<script>
function scrollit(){
 setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(1000);}, 1);
}
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `pagecontainershow` as it triggers after page is shown and JQM performes a default scroll to page's top.

```
$(document).one("pagecontainershow", function () {
   /* scroll */
});
```

Comment: @dramixx that event is the last to trigger in the sequence of pagecontainer events. Depending on device's speed, you may need to delay scrolling by 100ms in most cases.